# Product list randomly disappearing in Woocommerce shop page with W3TC

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I manage a Wordpress page that had this issue before, but after doing some caching configuration (W3TC) the product list in shop page started disappearing more frequently. The only thing that brings it back is opening the page in page editor and pressing "update", no changes should be made. Purging all cache also does not help (pages are built using DIVI page builder).

So far I have reverted all of the changes that were made before, but that has not decreased the frequency of the issue.
Because of the store being live, I am not inclined to do plugin uninstalls as it can damage the page even more (Issues of page CSS not loading properly were seen before, purging cache helped in that case)
One thing that I thought about is making some kind of script that updates the page automatically as a temporary solution (a new site is going to be made eventually)

What could be done to either troubleshoot this issue in safe way or at least create an automatic page update script?

-WordPress 5.1.1 running Divi theme, Woocommerce version 3.5.7-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Vladimir for the tip about preview mode. The bug unfortunately is not in the CSS though because minifying is not enabled in W3TC.
By "disappearing more frequently" I mean Header and Footer being fine and Body being only partly loaded - [Broken page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82XOT.jpg)

However, I have tracked down the issue to woocommerce itself. It seems like the default set shop page is the one crashing regularly. I did not find solution to the initial problem, but I found a trick that works, at least for now.
I created a new Shop page, but instead of linking it in Woocommerce settings, I just included a [products] shortcode. The previous page is still active, but not visible to user. Even if the shop page itself crashes, products are still visible and purchases are possible.

Answer (score 1):

You say page "started disappearing more frequently", do you mean page is loaded but content disappears or it whole page does not load?

Try turning off Minifying in W3TC. I had this problem few times and always a problem was typo in CSS.
In W3TC in General Setting there is possibility to enable Preview mode, turn this on always before deploying. Turn on preview mode, check if everything is Ok, test, search for bugs. And only when you are sure that everything works fine then deploy it.